# how do i display <something> in php without it being recognised as code?

Tags: php, html

Im working on a web based manager for my minecraft server. i have got to the point where i have it outputting lines from the server log file.

my problem is that whenever a player talks their name and text is displayed in the log like this `<playername> hello world` but when its passed into the html it identifies it as a tag and thus isnt printed into the log div.

my current code is as follows

```
<?php

// Parses text with control codes and returns HTML
function mclogparse($str) {

// Prevent HTML interpretation
$str = '<span id="mclogparse">'.htmlspecialchars($str);
// Colors
$fgColors = array(
    30 => 'black',
    31 => 'red',
    32 => 'green',
    33 => 'yellow',
    34 => '#0055ff', // blue
    35 => 'magenta',
    36 => 'cyan',
    37 => 'white'
);

// Replace color codes
foreach(array_keys($fgColors) as $color)
    //$str = preg_replace("/\x1B\[".$color.';(1m|22m)/','</span><span          style="color: '.$fgColors[$color].';">',$str);

// Replace "default" codes with closing span
$str = preg_replace("/\x1B\[(0;39|0;49)?m/",'</span>', $str);

// Color message types
$str = strtr($str,array(
    '[INFO]' => '[<span style="color: #77ccff;">INFO</span>]',
    '[WARNING]' => '[<span style="color: yellow;">WARNING</span>]',
    '[SEVERE]' => '[<span style="color: red;">SEVERE</span>]'
));

return $str;

}

// Strips control codes from log
function mclogclean($str) {
$str = preg_replace("/\x1B\[([0-9]+;([0-9]+;)?(1|22))?m/", "", $str);
return $str;
}
```

this code stops it from being recognised as a tag but also makes the line display as `hello world`
rather than `playername helloworld`

is there some way of making it print as playername: message?

Comment: How about using `str_replace('<', '&lt;', $str);` and `str_replace('>', '&gt;', $str);`?

Comment: You already have the answer in your code: `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @TomHart Use HTMLSpecialChars or html_encode_entities instead, writing your own method for this is daft and prone to errors.

Comment: so according to my code shouldnt it already work?

Comment: No, but you already know what to do: `// Prevent HTML interpretation`

Comment: @scragar oops, I forgot about that function, thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @jeroen $str = '<span id="mclogparse">'.htmlspecialchars($str); isnt enough?

Comment: I just ran your escaping function, and it appears to be escaping the html just fine for me.

Comment: If `$str` contains the string you don't want interpreted as html, it is. However, note that ID's have to be unique in a html page. What does `$str` contain exactly?

Comment: Could you post the HTML response of `mclogparse('<playername> hello world');`?

Comment: bearing in mind that in the log it says [15:11:55] [Server thread/INFO]: <Useruser3> hello world but when translated to the html it says [15:11:55] [Server thread/INFO]:" followed by an html tag <useruser3> hello world but on the actual page it shows [15:11:55] [Server thread/INFO]: hello world 
</useruser3>

Comment: Add the output of `var_dump($str);` to your question, without that, it is impossible to see what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape your tags with `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`, so it won't get interpretated as HTML by the browser.

If the data is already there, you can just run, at the begining of your function, something like :

```
$str = str_replace("<","&lt;", $str);
$str = str_replace(">","&gt;", $str);
```

You can also use htmlspecialchars to prevent any *html* character to be interpretated :

```
$str = htmlspecialchars($str);
```

If you just want your string to display as it is, this is the best way.

Comment: the problem is the data is being read from a file thats written by the  minecraft program

Comment: Edited my answer to take into account your comment :)

Comment: As @scragar mentioned in his comment, you should use `htmlspecialchars` instead of manually doing your own replacements.

Comment: would it be helpful if i pasted the class dealing with the log file?

Comment: changing the htmlspecialchars or any other functions on $str doesnt appear to be changing anything